# Realm dotnet migration callback not being called

Tags: xamarin, realm, database-migration

I am trying to implement realm migration using version v0.81.0

When I install and run the new version of the app with an additional field in one of my data access objects, instead of calling the realm migration callback it just throws an exception (RealmMigrationNeededException) telling me I have to migrate because I have added a property to one of my data access objects. This is my first attempt at migration therefore previously the callback to schema version was not set

Here is my code, can anyone see any issues. The encryption key used here is just for example purposes

```
        try
        {
            var config = new RealmConfiguration("MyExampleDatabase.realm");

            var encryptionKey = new byte[64] // key MUST be exactly this size
                {
              0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41,
              0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41,
              0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41,
              0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41,
              0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41,
              0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41,
              0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41,
              0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41,
                };

            config.EncryptionKey = encryptionKey;

            // Start of new code added
            config.MigrationCallback = (migration, oldSchemaVersion) =>
            {
                // do migration here!!
            };

            config.SchemaVersion = 1;
            // End of new code added
            var realm = Realm.GetInstance(config);
            return realm;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Log error here
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The Realm configuration's `SchemaVersion` has to change in order for the migration callback to be invoked.

### Example Migration

#### Initial RealmObject (SchemaVersion == 1)

```
public class POCO : RealmObject
{
    public string key { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

#### Initial App (SchemaVersion == 1)

```
const ulong currentSchemaVersion = 1;
var config = new RealmConfiguration()
{
    SchemaVersion = currentSchemaVersion,
    MigrationCallback = (Migration migration, ulong oldSchemaVersion) =>
    {
        // initial app release / no schema migration
        // This will NOT be called
    }
};
var realm = Realm.GetInstance(config);
realm.WriteAsync((Realm r) =>
{
    var data = new POCO()
    {
        key = "1",
        value = "1"
    };
    r.Add(data);
});
```

### RealmObject changed in new app release:

#### Updated RealmObject (SchemaVersion == 2)

**Note**: Type of `value` changed from `string` to `int`

```
public class POCO : RealmObject
{
    public string key { get; set; }
    public int value { get; set; }
}
```

#### Updated App (SchemaVersion == 2)

```
const ulong currentSchemaVersion = 2;
var config = new RealmConfiguration()
{
    SchemaVersion = currentSchemaVersion,
    MigrationCallback = (Migration migration, ulong oldSchemaVersion) =>
    {
        if (oldSchemaVersion > currentSchemaVersion)
        {
            throw new Exception($"SchemaVersion of {oldSchemaVersion} is unknown");
        }
        if (oldSchemaVersion <= 1)
        {
            // SchemaVersion = 1
            // initial app release / no schema migration
        }
        if (oldSchemaVersion < 2)
        {
            // SchemaVersion = 2,
            // POCO.value changed from string to int

            var newPOCOs = migration.NewRealm.All<POCO>();
            var oldPOCOs = migration.OldRealm.All("POCO");
            var count = newPOCOs.Count();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                var oldPOCO = oldPOCOs.ElementAt(i);
                var newPOCO = newPOCOs.ElementAt(i);
                newPOCO.value = int.Parse(oldPOCO.value);
            }
        }
    }
};
var realm = Realm.GetInstance(config);
realm.WriteAsync((Realm r) =>
{
    var data = new POCO()
    {
        key = "2",
        value = 2
    };
    r.Add(data);
});
```

Comment: I understand that. According to the documentation "When unspecified, realms will have a schema version set to 0. " So my original app had no schema version set and so can assumed to be version 0. In the next version as shown above I set it to 1. So I am expecting the migration callback to be invoked. So why is it not being called?

Comment: @rideintothesun You state your Realm version is 0.88.1, that version does not exist..(0.82.0 is the current version), . What Realm version did your original database get created with and what version are you currently on? i.e. that change to initialize the schema to 0 was done in github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/pull/768 ...

Comment: Sorry that should have read 0.81.0. This is what I am doing my initial development investigation on. My in production version is 0.77.1. Will this be able to be migrated?

Comment: My real question now is if I have an app in production written using v0.77.1 and now want to upgrade the app to one which uses v0.81.0, will it detect the migration. If not can I force a migration to happen to bridge a version of realm that does not support migrations to one that does?

Comment: @rideintothesun There are multiple ways to "kludge" it, but maybe the Realm devs will have a better way : https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/issues/1186

Comment: I have a long answer below but maybe the confounding thing is that you have encryption enabled, so am testing further.

Comment: So far I have tested it on Xamarin for Android. Here are the details - Realm 0.88.1
Windows 7 SP1
Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Version 14.0.25420.1 with Nuget Package Manager 3.4.4
Xamarin 4.1.2.18
Xamarin.Android 6.1.2.21
Xamarin.iOS 9.8.2.22 I am in the middle of an upgrade on my dev machine so will try it again when I am up to date

Comment: Any further word on this Andy?

Comment: @rideintothesun https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/issues/1186#issuecomment-275398669

Answer (score 1):

**Summary**

Migrations work, even if the old version of the Realm predates them.

Encryption makes no difference.

**Original**

@sushihangover is right but there are more nuances.

Simply adding a property **should not require a callback** unless you want custom logic to populate it. The property would be added automatically in the Realm.

However, to ensure you *intended* to change the schema, the minimum migration is to bump the schema number, as [we document](https://realm.io/docs/xamarin/latest/#performing-a-migration).

It seemed like there might be a problem that you started with 0.77.1. Looking at the [changelog, 0.77.2](https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0772-2016-08-11) was the version introducing a fix *Schema version numbers now start at 0 rather than UInt64.MaxValue*

However:

**Update with test results**

**Simple Migration**

1. I built an app with 0.77.1 nuget and ran on an iPhone
2. I copied the solution and updated my copy to 0.81.0 by first removing Realm then adding the 0.81.0 package.
3. In the copy, I added a simple integer property.
4. Running the migrated copy *just worked*

These results surprised me a bit - I thought I would need to explicitly set `SchemaVersion`.

But then I realised that the default `SchemaVersion` being 0 in 0.81.0 probably works because the old `UInt64.MaxValue` was handled as being *unassigned*.

**Callback Test**

1. Taking the two solutions above, I added a callback method as described [in our Migration docs](https://realm.io/docs/xamarin/latest/#performing-a-migration).
2. The migration callback was not invoked, unsurprisingly.
3. I explicitly set a new `config.SchemaVersion` and my migration callback was invoked.

Bottom line - it all worked as expected.

**Callback Test - purely in 0.81.0**
I realised on re-reading the question that your experiments with migration are **not** starting with a 0.77.1 Realm but in 0.81.0.

1. I started in 0.81.0 with my minimal schema and ran, so the Realm was created.
2. I added a property and my migration callback.
3. I set the `SchemaVersion=1`
4. I ran and the migration callback was invoked (implies initial `SchemaVersion` was 0).

This leaves me a bit confused as to what actually happened to trigger your exception because it appears that everything is working as documented and expected with 0.81.0, whether migrating from an old 0.71.1 or current 0.81.0 Realm.

Following another theory as I mentioned in a comment on the question, I tried adding encryption to see if that made a difference (no).